# Average of 26 Mbit/s how many GBs/month?

Tags: bandwidth

I need to know how many data my server transfer over a month.

I know from my control panel only my average Mbit/s daily that is:  **26Mb/s**.

Doing some calc:

26Mbit/s = 3.25 Mbyte/s

- Daily usage: 86400 (seconds) * 3.25 (Mbyte/s) = 280'800 Megabyte
- Month usage: 30*280800 = 8'424'000 Megabyte

So each month my server transfer `8000 GB` (8 TB). Is it correct?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That's about right. Your monthly usage at 26Mb/s would be 8.541 terabytes.

[Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=26Mb%2Fs+for+1+month) is very useful for calculations like these. You simply type "26Mb/s for 1 month" as the search term and get the following output:

> #### Input interpretation:
>
> 26 Mb/s  (megabits per second) × 1 month
>
> #### Result
>
> 6.833×10^7 Mb  (megabits)
>
> #### Unit conversions
>
> 68.33 Tb  (terabits)
> 6.833×10^13 bits
> 8.541 TB  (terabytes)

Comment: +10 for wolframalpha

Comment: Just a quick tip: if you add the unit you want to convert to, it will do all the hard work for you: just input "26Mb/s for 1 month **to GB**" as the search term.